# Getting Missing expression after '=' error in powershell build step

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I am working on a team city build step. This is a powershell step in which I am using %teamcity.build.branch% and %teamcity.build.checkoutDirectory% parameters. Here is the script:

```
param([string]$branchName=%teamcity.build.branch%, [string]$bldCheckOutDir=%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%)

write "Value of branchName is $branchName"
write "Value of bldCheckOutDir is $bldCheckOutDir"

if ($branchName.Substring(0,1) -like "F") {Write "Working on a Feature Branch"; CD $bldCheckOutDir\DCD-GUI; npm test; sonar-scanner -X}
elseif ($branchName.Substring(0,2) -like "US") {Write "Working on a Story Branch"}
elseif ($branchName.Substring(0,2) -like "DE") {Write "Working on a Defect Branch"}
elseif ($branchName.Substring(0,2) -like "QA") {Write "Working on a QA1 Branch"; CD $bldCheckOutDir\DCD-GUI; npm test; CD ..; FortifyBatchFile.bat; sonar-scanner -X; }
else {Write "BranchName not known"}
```

When I run this script as a build step in a build configuration, I get below error:

> [Step 4/4] Working directory: E:\BuildAgent\work\d429bf6e9117eae6
>   [04:25:58][Step 4/4] PowerShell arguments: [-NonInteractive,
>   -ExecutionPolicy, ByPass, -File, E:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell6621137048056018482.ps1]
>   [04:26:08][Step 4/4] Missing expression after '='. [04:26:08][Step
>   4/4] At
>   E:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell6621137048056018482.ps1:1
>   char:27 [04:26:08][Step 4/4] + param([string]$branchName= <<<< qa1,
>   [string]$bldCheckOutDir=E:\BuildAgent\wo [04:26:08][Step 4/4]
>   rk\d429bf6e9117eae6) [04:26:08][Step 4/4]     + CategoryInfo
>   : ParserError: (=:String) [], ParentContainsErrorR  [04:26:08][Step
>   4/4]    ecordException [04:26:08][Step 4/4]     +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paramter block, you need to enclose the teamcity variables in either double or single quotes:

```
param(
    [string]$branchName = "%teamcity.build.branch%",
    [string]$bldCheckOutDir = "%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%"
)
```

Without them the `%` character is likely being treated as a special character.

Comment: so whats the point of the second one as this is exactly the same he is usin? O_o

Comment: @Mark, teamcity.build.branch is a predefined configuration parameter in teamcity and teamcity.build.checkoutDir is a predefined Agent build property in teamcity. So, I have not defined any of these parameters myself. I am just using what teamcity provides me for those variable while running the build. Do I still need to treat those as environment variables ?

Comment: I think the error is just occurring because you're not using double quotes or single quotes around them, and as such its treating the % character as a special character. Might be wrong though.

Comment: Mark, your update is correct, as well as your comments above; your original text (about environment variables) is not. I think it's best to remove that part completely.